# database size question

Tags: database

How much database space would you need to hold user information for 100,000 users?

Comment: What information do you want to store for each user?  What database? ...

Comment: Somewhere in the range `(-∞, ∞)`

Comment: Maybe `[0, ∞)` would work too. On average, you'll need `∞ mb`.

Answer (score 2):

That depends heavily upon *what* information you hold.

If it's a username, an MD5 of a password, and a few short fields, I'd say:

```
6 + 32 + 5 x 200 = 1,038 bytes ~ 1,040 bytes
```

So for `100,000` records, I'd say that:

```
1,040 x 100,000 = 104,000,000 ~ 100,000,000 bytes
```

Which is around `100 mb`.

Not that much.

Answer (score 1):

100,000 times the amount of database space you would need for 1 user.

Comment: Or 200,000 times the amount of database space you'd need for half a user!